# Не моку скомпилировать,но если начать проверять код то он работает,а приложение само нет в чем проблема в заранее спасибо

Tags: python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk
    import datetime
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    day=int(x.day)
    month=int(x.month)
    year=int(x.year)
    ask=3

```
if    (day<10):
    day=str("0")+str(day)
if    (month<10):
    month=str("0")+str(month)

window=Tk()
window.title("Помошник огорода")
window.geometry("700x1000")


yearl=Label()
dayl=Label(text="",font="Arial 20 italic")
monthl=Label(text="",font="Arial 20 italic")
dayl=Label(text="",font="Arial 20 italic")
dayl.place(x=10,y=30)
monthl=Label(text="",font="Arial 20 italic")
monthl.place(x=165,y=30)
yearl=Label(text="",font="Arial 20 italic")
yearl.place(x=205,y=30)
monthl["text"]=""+str(month)+str(".")
dayl["text"]="Сегодня:"+str(x.day)+str(".")
yearl["text"]=""+str(year)


f1=open("year.txt")
g=int(*f1)
f2=open("day.txt")
d=int(*f2)
f3=open("month.txt")
m=int(*f3)
if    (d<10):
    d=str("0")+str(d)
if    (m<10):
   m=str("0")+str(m)
gs=str(g)

ds=str(d)
ms=str(m)
dfg=str(ds)+str(".")+str(ms)+str(".")+str(gs)
pdpol=Label(text="Последняя дата полива:",font="Arial 20 italic")
pdpol.place(x=10,y=60)
pdpol["text"]="Последняя дата полива:"+str(dfg)
dp=int(ds)
mp=int(ms)
gp=int(gs)
cmd8 = lambda : izmy()



from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

label=Label(window,text="После изменения даты полива не забудте перезагрузить  программу!!!",font="Decor 15",fg="#FF0000")
label.place(x=17,y=400)
combo = Combobox(window)  
combo['values'] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)
combo.place(x=250,y=500)
combo.current(0)
combo1 = Combobox(window)
combo1['values']= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
combo1.place(x=250,y=540)
combo1.current(0)
combo2 = Combobox(window)
combo2['values']= (2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032, 2033, 2034, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2038, 2039, 2040, 2041, 2042, 2043, 2044, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2048, 2049, 2050, 2051, 2052, 2053, 2054, 2055, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2059, 2060, 2061, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2066, 2067, 2068, 2069, 2070, 2071, 2072, 2073, 2074, 2075, 2076, 2077, 2078, 2079, 2080, 2081, 2082, 2083, 2084, 2085, 2086, 2087, 2088, 2089, 2090, 2091, 2092, 2093, 2094, 2095, 2096, 2097, 2098, 2099, 2100, 2101, 2102, 2103, 2104, 2105, 2106, 2107, 2108, 2109, 2110, 2111, 2112, 2113, 2114, 2115, 2116, 2117, 2118, 2119, 2120, 2121, 2122, 2123, 2124, 2125, 2126, 2127, 2128, 2129, 2130, 2131, 2132, 2133, 2134, 2135, 2136, 2137, 2138, 2139, 2140, 2141, 2142, 2143, 2144, 2145, 2146, 2147, 2148, 2149, 2150, 2151, 2152, 2153, 2154, 2155, 2156, 2157, 2158, 2159, 2160, 2161, 2162, 2163, 2164, 2165, 2166, 2167, 2168, 2169, 2170, 2171, 2172, 2173, 2174, 2175, 2176, 2177, 2178, 2179, 2180, 2181, 2182, 2183, 2184, 2185, 2186, 2187, 2188, 2189, 2190, 2191, 2192, 2193, 2194, 2195, 2196, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200, 2201, 2202, 2203, 2204, 2205, 2206, 2207, 2208, 2209, 2210, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2214, 2215, 2216, 2217, 2218, 2219, 2220, 2221, 2222, 2223, 2224, 2225, 2226, 2227, 2228, 2229, 2230, 2231, 2232, 2233, 2234, 2235, 2236, 2237, 2238, 2239, 2240, 2241, 2242, 2243, 2244, 2245, 2246, 2247, 2248, 2249, 2250, 2251, 2252, 2253, 2254, 2255, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2259, 2260, 2261, 2262, 2263, 2264, 2265, 2266, 2267, 2268, 2269, 2270, 2271, 2272, 2273, 2274, 2275, 2276, 2277, 2278, 2279, 2280, 2281, 2282, 2283, 2284, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2302, 2303, 2304, 2305, 2306, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2314, 2315, 2316, 2317, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2324, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2328, 2329, 2330, 2331, 2332, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2336, 2337, 2338, 2339, 2340, 2341, 2342, 2343, 2344, 2345, 2346, 2347, 2348, 2349, 2350, 2351, 2352, 2353, 2354, 2355, 2356, 2357, 2358, 2359, 2360, 2361, 2362, 2363, 2364, 2365, 2366, 2367, 2368, 2369, 2370, 2371, 2372, 2373, 2374, 2375, 2376, 2377, 2378, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2382, 2383, 2384, 2385, 2386, 2387, 2388, 2389, 2390, 2391, 2392, 2393, 2394, 2395, 2396, 2397, 2398, 2399, 2400, 2401, 2402, 2403, 2404, 2405, 2406, 2407, 2408, 2409, 2410, 2411, 2412, 2413, 2414, 2415, 2416, 2417, 2418, 2419, 2420, 2421, 2422, 2423, 2424, 2425, 2426, 2427, 2428, 2429, 2430, 2431, 2432, 2433, 2434, 2435, 2436, 2437, 2438, 2439, 2440, 2441, 2442, 2443, 2444, 2445, 2446, 2447, 2448, 2449, 2450, 2451, 2452, 2453, 2454, 2455, 2456, 2457, 2458, 2459, 2460, 2461, 2462, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2467, 2468, 2469, 2470, 2471, 2472, 2473, 2474, 2475, 2476, 2477, 2478, 2479, 2480, 2481, 2482, 2483, 2484, 2485, 2486, 2487, 2488, 2489, 2490, 2491, 2492, 2493, 2494, 2495, 2496, 2497, 2498, 2499, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2503, 2504, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2512, 2513, 2514, 2515, 2516, 2517, 2518, 2519, 2520, 2521, 2522, 2523, 2524, 2525, 2526, 2527, 2528, 2529, 2530, 2531, 2532, 2533, 2534, 2535, 2536, 2537, 2538, 2539, 2540, 2541, 2542, 2543, 2544, 2545, 2546, 2547, 2548, 2549, 2550, 2551, 2552, 2553, 2554, 2555, 2556, 2557, 2558, 2559, 2560, 2561, 2562, 2563, 2564, 2565, 2566, 2567, 2568, 2569, 2570, 2571, 2572, 2573, 2574, 2575, 2576, 2577, 2578, 2579, 2580, 2581, 2582, 2583, 2584, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2590, 2591, 2592, 2593, 2594, 2595, 2596, 2597, 2598, 2599, 2600, 2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2607, 2608, 2609, 2610, 2611, 2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2618, 2619, 2620, 2621, 2622, 2623, 2624, 2625, 2626, 2627, 2628, 2629, 2630, 2631, 2632, 2633, 2634, 2635, 2636, 2637, 2638, 2639, 2640, 2641, 2642, 2643, 2644, 2645, 2646, 2647, 2648, 2649, 2650, 2651, 2652, 2653, 2654, 2655, 2656, 2657, 2658, 2659, 2660, 2661, 2662, 2663, 2664, 2665, 2666, 2667, 2668, 2669, 2670, 2671, 2672, 2673, 2674, 2675, 2676, 2677, 2678, 2679, 2680, 2681, 2682, 2683, 2684, 2685, 2686, 2687, 2688, 2689, 2690, 2691, 2692, 2693, 2694, 2695, 2696, 2697, 2698, 2699, 2700, 2701, 2702, 2703, 2704, 2705, 2706, 2707, 2708, 2709, 2710, 2711, 2712, 2713, 2714, 2715, 2716, 2717, 2718, 2719, 2720, 2721, 2722, 2723, 2724, 2725, 2726, 2727, 2728, 2729, 2730, 2731, 2732, 2733, 2734, 2735, 2736, 2737, 2738, 2739, 2740, 2741, 2742, 2743, 2744, 2745, 2746, 2747, 2748, 2749, 2750, 2751, 2752, 2753, 2754, 2755, 2756, 2757, 2758, 2759, 2760, 2761, 2762, 2763, 2764, 2765, 2766, 2767, 2768, 2769, 2770, 2771, 2772, 2773, 2774, 2775, 2776, 2777, 2778, 2779, 2780, 2781, 2782, 2783, 2784, 2785, 2786, 2787, 2788, 2789, 2790, 2791, 2792, 2793, 2794, 2795, 2796, 2797, 2798, 2799, 2800, 2801, 2802, 2803, 2804, 2805, 2806, 2807, 2808, 2809, 2810, 2811, 2812, 2813, 2814, 2815, 2816, 2817, 2818, 2819, 2820, 2821, 2822, 2823, 2824, 2825, 2826, 2827, 2828, 2829, 2830, 2831, 2832, 2833, 2834, 2835, 2836, 2837, 2838, 2839, 2840, 2841, 2842, 2843, 2844, 2845, 2846, 2847, 2848, 2849, 2850, 2851, 2852, 2853, 2854, 2855, 2856, 2857, 2858, 2859, 2860, 2861, 2862, 2863, 2864, 2865, 2866, 2867, 2868, 2869, 2870, 2871, 2872, 2873, 2874, 2875, 2876, 2877, 2878, 2879, 2880, 2881, 2882, 2883, 2884, 2885, 2886, 2887, 2888, 2889, 2890, 2891, 2892, 2893, 2894, 2895, 2896, 2897, 2898, 2899, 2900, 2901, 2902, 2903, 2904, 2905, 2906, 2907, 2908, 2909, 2910, 2911, 2912, 2913, 2914, 2915, 2916, 2917, 2918, 2919, 2920, 2921, 2922, 2923, 2924, 2925, 2926, 2927, 2928, 2929, 2930, 2931, 2932, 2933, 2934, 2935, 2936, 2937, 2938, 2939, 2940, 2941, 2942, 2943, 2944, 2945, 2946, 2947, 2948, 2949, 2950, 2951, 2952, 2953, 2954, 2955, 2956, 2957, 2958, 2959, 2960, 2961, 2962, 2963, 2964, 2965, 2966, 2967, 2968, 2969, 2970, 2971, 2972, 2973, 2974, 2975, 2976, 2977, 2978, 2979, 2980, 2981, 2982, 2983, 2984, 2985, 2986, 2987, 2988, 2989, 2990, 2991, 2992, 2993, 2994, 2995, 2996, 2997, 2998, 2999,3000)
combo2.place(x=250,y=580)
combo2.current(0)
ml=Label(window,text="Укажите год:",font="Arial 20 italic")
ml.place(x=10,y=570)
ml=Label(window,text="Укажите месяц:",font="Arial 20 italic")
ml.place(x=10,y=530)
dl=Label(window,text="Укажите день:",font="Arial 20 italic")
dl.place(x=10,y=490)

izm=Button(window,text="Изменить дату",font="Arial 15 italic",command=cmd8)
izm.place(x=10,y=650)
def  izmy():
    dss=str(combo.get())
    mss=str(combo1.get())
    gss=str(combo2.get())
    with open("day.txt",'w',encoding = 'cp1252') as f:
        f.write(dss)
    with open("month.txt",'w',encoding = 'cp1252') as f:
        f.write(mss)
    with open("year.txt",'w',encoding = 'cp1252') as f:
        f.write(gss)

def cmdy():
    import datetime
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    day=str(x.day)
    month=str(x.month)
    year=str(x.year)
    with open("day.txt",'w',encoding = 'cp1252') as f:
        f.write(day)
    with open("month.txt",'w',encoding = 'cp1252') as f:
        f.write(month)
    with open("year.txt",'w',encoding = 'cp1252') as f:
        f.write(year)


cmd = lambda : cmdy()

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="water.jpg")
poliv=Button(window,image=image,font="Arial 20 italic",width=100,command=cmd)
poliv.place(x=570,y=5)
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="perez.jpg")




dayold=int(ds)
monthold=int(ms)
f1=open("year.txt")
yearold=int(*f1)


x = datetime.datetime.now()
days=int(x.day)
months=int(x.month)
years=int(x.year)


s=0
for i in range(yearold,years):
    if  (i%4==0):
        sd=366
    else:
        sd=365
    if  (i%100==0 and i%4==0 and i%400==0):
        sd=366
    if  (i%100==0 and i%4==0 and i%400!=0):
        sd=365
    s+=sd
sdg=s
sm=0
for i in range(monthold,months):
    if    (sd==365):
        if    (i<=7 and i%2==0 and i!=2):
            sm+=30
        if    (i<=7 and i%2==1):
            sm+=31
        if  (i==2):
            sm+=28
        if  (i>7 and i%2==0):
            sm+=31
        if  (i>7 and i%2==1):
            sm+=30
    if    (sd==366):
        if    (i<=7 and i%2==0 and i!=2):
            sm+=30
        if    (i<=7 and i%2==1):
            sm+=31
        if  (i==2):
            sm+=29
        if  (i>7 and i%2==0):
            sm+=31
        if  (i>7 and i%2==1):
            sm+=30
sm=sm
day=days-dayold
proshlidays=sm+sdg+day


al=Label(text="",font="Arial 20 italic")
al["text"]="Прошло дней от последнего полива:"+str(proshlidays)
al.place(x=10,y=90)
mainloop()
```

Comment: 'не работает' бывает разное, приложите тексты ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Всё я уже нашел проблему он не мог найти файлов которые ему нужны для работы они были в другой папке а полный путь к ним у меня не был указан.